# Ruby 1.8.7 error using sort_by

Tags: ruby, sorting

[Extending the geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/pull/553), I am trying to support Ruby version 1.8.7, 1.9.2 and 1.9.3.

In 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 everything works fine, but in 1.8.7, when I try to run:

```
hashes.sort_by{ |key, value| value }
```

it gives me

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `<=>' for nil:NilClass
```

My `hashes` array looks like this:

```
[
  {"u33dc0cpnnf4j6c9vksk7zzp"=>1},
  {"u33ddph3wbe2cjnfnxe98sn0"=>1},
  {"u33616p4rb8vtm9uscy26f5b"=>1}
]
```

Looking at the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), it doesn't seem to be using `<=>` anywhere in the source for `sort_by`.

What's causing this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby internally uses `<=>` to compare while sorting.

I think there is a missunderstanding in the block for `sort_by`: you get an array element as block argument, not the key/values of the hashes. So `value`  always is `nil`. And while in Ruby >=1.9 `nil <=> nil` is zero, there is no `<=>` method on `nil` for Ruby 1.8.

So what you have to do is the `sort_by` call, for example to something like this:

```
hashes = [
  {"u33dc0cpnnf4j6c9vksk7zzp"=>1},
  {"u33ddph3wbe2cjnfnxe98sn0"=>1},
  {"u33616p4rb8vtm9uscy26f5b"=>1}
]

hashes.sort_by { |val| val.values.first }
```

This sorts by the first value of each hash.